# C# LZW Compression and Decompression

Tags: c#, algorithm, lzw

I have looked at the SharpZipLib library, but i do not know how i would use the LZW in that library.
For example i have a `List<int>` of bits, which i want to compress.

Lets say `List<int> bits` contains the following elements `{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1}`

How could i compress this using LZW SharpZipLib or any other LZW library.

I have tried looking at the documentation and `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Lzw`, but i haven't found anything that would help me compress the `List<int>` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpZibLib only allows [decompressing LZW](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Lzw.LzwInputStream.html) from a particular format, namely the [Z file format](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development:_Z_File_Format).

See the Stack Overflow question [LZW Data Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713850/lzw-data-compression) for code to compress data using LZW. As for your data, I'd suggest packing those bits into bytes, create a byte array from a [BitArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560123/convert-from-bitarray-to-byte), then a MemoryStream over that byte array.

So something like this:

```
var bitArray = new BitArray(bits.Select(b => b == 1).ToArray());
var byteArray = new byte[bits.Length / 8];
bitArray.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
// do the compression magic on byteArray, or a new MemoryStream(byteArray)
```